# Confirm email field

Tags: php, html

I am creating a subscribe to us newsletter page, everything else works perfectly fine, but i'm trying to get the user to insert their email twice, the 2nd email field should work as a "confirm email" field. I'm have a little trouble doing so. Could someone lend a land?

If the 2nd email field does not match the 1st email field, it should display an error message

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    if (trim($fv->txt_Email) == '') {
        $e->defineError("email_required", "Please provide your email address.", "txt_Email");
    } elseif (!cmsValidation::isValidEmail($fv->txt_Email)) {
        $e->defineError("invalid_email", "Please enter a valid email address.", "txt_Email");
    }
    if (trim($fv->txt_Email2) == '') {
        $e->defineError("email_required2", "Please confirm your email Address", "txt_Email2");
    } elseif (!cmsValidation::isValidEmail($fv->txt_Email2)) {
        $e->defineError("invalid_email", "Please enter a valid email address.", "txt_Email2");
    }
```

Comment: In what way does this code not work?  If you've already successfully added the first email field, what's preventing you from adding the second one?

Comment: I want to compare the 2nd email field to the second, to ensure the email addresses entered are identical to each other, if they are not the same, display an error message

Comment: Why don't you simply add comparison of the two trimmed mails?

Comment: `if($email_1 !== $email_2)` ?

Comment: It's obvious you want, but the questions is, why did you not?

Comment: @PHPLearner: You mean like this?  `if (trim($fv->txt_Email) != trim($fv->txt_Email2))`

Comment: `if($something == $another_thing){ // do something }else{...}`

Comment: jesus, i started to otherthink this way to much and forgot that it was a simple solution, thanks guys, if someone wants to enter this is an answer ill up vote it. Thanks, had a stupid moment.

Comment: @PHPLearner I think it's up to David to enter it as an answer, since he was the one to come up with it first, looking at the timestamp.

Comment: @David I suggest you make it (your comment) an answer (maybe adding a quick explanation too), since your comment was in fact first and looks to me like it answered the question.

Comment: Davids answer made it work, but the guy who answered below also gave me code that works. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: @PHPLearner Yeah, it's a bit of a tough call. But looking at the timestamps between David's comment and the answer given, it's clear that the time difference is rather wide; a full 60 seconds. A lot can happen in 60 seconds ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply compare the two fields like you do with any other validation check in this code...

```
if (trim($fv->txt_Email) != trim($fv->txt_Email2)) {
    $e->defineError("email_mismatch", "Please ensure your email addresses match", "txt_Email2");
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, been coding for hours so a little brain dead, thanks for this. Just one little thing more, i'm testing to make sure this works, when an incorrect email is entered and submitted, the code recognises that the two emails are not the same, gives me the user error message, but then copies the email from the 1st field to the second. Not sure why it does this.

Comment: @PHPLearner: That sounds like it would be a problem elsewhere in the code.  Perhaps whatever mechanism is echo-ing the form back to the user has a typo somewhere.

Comment: Yep, right, eveyrthing works fine I think need a break. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (trim($fv->txt_Email2) != $fv->txt_Email) {
        $e->defineError("invalid_email", "Your Email address do not match", "txt_Email2");
```